# How does std::visit work with std::variant?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm looking at `std:variant`/`std::visit` doc here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit and also googled a lot trying to understand the magic behind `std::visit` and `std::variant`.

So my question is the following. In the provided example, both in the **polymorphic lambda** and the "overloaded" there is some "magic" happening that makes it possible to extract the correct type from `std::variant`.

So looking at this:

```
for (auto& v: vec) {
    std::visit(overloaded {
        [](auto arg) { std::cout << arg << ' '; },
        [](double arg) { std::cout << std::fixed << arg << ' '; },
        [](const std::string& arg) { std::cout << std::quoted(arg) << ' '; },
    }, v);
}
```

For each `v`, which is just a variant, how does the right overloaded lambda function being invoked? It seems there is some logic that needs to figure out the exact type held by the specific `std::variant`, cast it and dispatch it to the proper function. My question is how does it work? Same deal for this:

```
    std::visit([](auto&& arg) {
        using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
            std::cout << "int with value " << arg << '\n';
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, long>)
            std::cout << "long with value " << arg << '\n';
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
            std::cout << "double with value " << arg << '\n';
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
            std::cout << "std::string with value " << std::quoted(arg) << '\n';
        else 
            static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "non-exhaustive visitor!");
    }, w);
```

We pass polymorphic lambda to the visitor as the callable object and `w` is some variant that can hold int, long, double or std::string.  Where is the logic that figures out the right type so `using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;` to retrieve the actual type of the specific instance of a variant?

Comment: Are you asking for the implementation of `std::visit`?

Comment: @cpplearner - probably :)

Comment: https://mpark.github.io/programming/2015/07/07/variant-visitation/

Comment: @Casey thanks. seems like index() and get<I> is the answer to the above. thanks for the link!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What I think, is that under the hood `std::visit` builds an array of function pointers (at compile time) which consists of instantiated function pointers for **each type**. The variant stores a run-time type index `i` (intgeral number) which makes it possible to select the right `i`-th function pointer and inject the value.

You might wonder how can we store function pointers with different argument types in a compile time array? -> This is done with type-erasure (I think), which means
one stores functions with e.g. a `void*` argument, e.g. `&A<T>::call`:

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
   static call(void*p) { otherFunction(static_cast<T*>(p)); } 
}
```

where each `call` dispatches to the correct function `otherFunction` with the argument (this is your lambda at the end).
Type erasure means the function `auto f = &A<T>::call` has no more notion of the type `T` and has signature `void(*)(void*)`.

`std::variant` is really complicated and quite sophisticated as lots of powerful fancy metaprogramming tricks come into play. This answer might only cover the tip of the iceberg :-)

Comment: Type erasure is not needed. Based on symbol names in compiler output (libstdc++), the array of function pointers is actually a static array of invoker objects that will call  std::get<T>on each of the variant with T corresponding to one of the invoker template arguments. The same callable is then used by all invokers on the casted variants. If the callable is a lambda(auto), the compiler will specialize the lambda for each case. In the other case, regular implicit conversion will take place when binding parameters.