# auto return type of a function which can return an object of sibling

Tags: c++, c++14, auto

I have  two classes which are inheriting from class `Base`

```cpp
struct Base
{
   virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived_1:public Base
{
  public:
     void getSomeFunc();
};

class Derived_2:public Base
{
  public:
     void getSomeFunc();
};
```

Now what I want to write a function which takes base class pointer object and after dynamic casting finding the appropriate child and returns it so that we can call right version of `getSomeFunc()`

I tried to write

```
auto getChild(Base* ptr)
{
  Derived_1 * p = dynamic_cast<Derived_1*>(ptr)
  if(p)
  {
    return p;
  }
  else
  {
      Derived_2 * q = dynamic_cast<Derived_2*>(ptr)
      if(q)
      {
        return q;
      }
     else
     { 
        // some handling to avoid bugs!!
     }
  }
```

But It does not get compiled. Any way to serve my requirement.

Edit 1 ----------------------------------
Error  from compiler is - `incorrect deduction of 'auto'`.
Compile is `gcc`

Comment: When asking about build errors, always please include the actual errors you get. Copy-paste them (as text), in full and complete, and show us where in the code the errors are (through comments).

Comment: Please add information on what it is you are trying to achieve here. What is `getChild()` actually supposed to do? It just does a `dynamic_cast` and returns the same pointer it was passed in. That doesn't look like it serves any purpose.

Comment: @NikosC. getChild() will return instance of one of the siblings. Then we will invoke getSomeFunc() on that instance. Also getSomeFunc() is in child classes and not in base class. Bad design!!. But one of the library I am using has this kind of hierarchy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly not what you want to do. Instead,  use a virtual method:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void getSomeFunc() = 0;
    // ... etc etc ...
};
```

then, you could write:

```
Base* ptr = get_a_base_instance_ptr_from_somewhere();
ptr->getSomeFunc();
```

In your code, you were trying to have `auto` have *either* the type of `p` or the type of `q`. But `auto` only has a *single* type. And a type which can accept both a pointer to `Derived_1` and a pointer to `Derived_2` is... yes, you guessed it: `Base*`.

**edit:** If you are unable to change the `Base`, `Derived_1` and `Derived_2` class, you could consider using `std::variant<Derived_1*, Derived_2*>`, and using visitation to call the appropriate method for each of these types. If you haven't used variants before, see the [CPP-reference page on `std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).  For information on how to write a visitor for use with a variant, see this SO question:

[How does std::visit work with std::variant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956335/how-does-stdvisit-work-with-stdvariant)

Comment: Base , Derived_1 and Derived_2 is not my class. But I have given you example from one of the library I am using.

Comment: getSomeFunc() is not in Base class.

Comment: @gauravbharadwaj: I see. Well, I've added a suggestion for this case as well.

Comment: did you suggested C++17 solution for this. I am using C++14 compliant compiler.

Comment: @gauravbharadwaj: You can get a C++14-compatible variant implementation, e.g. [Michael Park's variant](https://github.com/mpark/variant).