# How does std::visit handle multiple variants?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Related to, but not the same question as *[How does std::visit work with std::variant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47956335)*

Implementing `std::visit` for a single variant conceptually looks like this (in C++ pseudocode):

```cpp
template<class F, class... Ts>
void visit(F&& f, variant<Ts...>&& var) {
  using caller_type = void(*)(void*);
  caller_type dispatch[] = {dispatch_visitor(f, (INDEX_SEQUENCE))...};
  dispatch[var.index()](var);
};
```

Basically, we set up a jump table that calls the correct dispatcher for our visitor.

For multiple variants, it seems to be more complicated, as for this approach you'd need to compute the Cartesian product of all the variants' alternatives and possibly template thousands of functions. Is this how it's done or is there a better way that standard libraries implement it?

Comment: What leads you to believe that a cartesian product is needed? All that needs to be done is to dispatch one variant at a time.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik how does it resolve between to operators `a, a` and `a, b`? Clearly, you have to choose one of them depending on your second variant's active value

Comment: No, that's not how `std::visit` works, with multiple variants.

Comment: @samv No, std visit can be demonstrated to require the cartesian product.  I am not sure what you think it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> For multiple variants, it seems to be more complicated, as for this
> approach you'd need to compute the Cartesian product of all the
> variants' alternatives and possibly template thousands of functions.

There are currently two implementations of multi-variant visitation.

GCC constructs a [*multi-dimensional function table*](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/variant#L1747) at compile time according to the number of alternative types of variants, and access the corresponding visit function through multiple indexes at runtime.

```
// Use a jump table for the general case.
constexpr auto& __vtable = __detail::__variant::__gen_vtable< 
                             _Result_type, _Visitor&&, _Variants&&...>::_S_vtable;
auto __func_ptr = __vtable._M_access(__variants.index()...);
return (*__func_ptr)(std::forward<_Visitor>(__visitor),
                     std::forward<_Variants>(__variants)...);
```

MSVC uses [*recursive switch-case*](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/variant#L665) to perform multi-variant visitation:

```
#define _STL_VISIT_STAMP(stamper, n)                                               \
    constexpr size_t _Size = _Variant_total_states<_Remove_cvref_t<_Variants>...>; \
    static_assert(_Size > (n) / 4 && _Size <= (n));                                \
    switch (_Idx) {                                                                \
        stamper(0, _STL_CASE);                                                     \
    default:                                                                       \
        _STL_UNREACHABLE;                                                          \
    }
```

This switch-case base implementation has better performance when the number of variants is small or the number of alternatives is small, which also makes GCC use this approach for simple cases in [its recent patch](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/cfb582f62791dfadc243d97d37f0b83ef77cf480#diff-42d34e2570773e3c256c114cc9371f613ed6fbb68be254f3ab008d872d630c6b) to reduce the instantiation of function tables.

```
switch (__v0.index())
{
  _GLIBCXX_VISIT_CASE(0)
  _GLIBCXX_VISIT_CASE(1)
  _GLIBCXX_VISIT_CASE(2)
  _GLIBCXX_VISIT_CASE(3)
  _GLIBCXX_VISIT_CASE(4)
  case variant_npos:
          // ...
}
```

You can refer to the following two blogs by Michael Park for more implementation details:

- [Variant Visitation](https://mpark.github.io/programming/2015/07/07/variant-visitation/)
- [Variant Visitation V2](https://mpark.github.io/programming/2019/01/22/variant-visitation-v2/)